# regex to cross over multiple lines with finditer

Tags: python, regex-group, regex-lookarounds

I am working on a regex that would parse the logs into groups to write into a df.
Some of the log events break over multiple lines.
I am doing this jupyter notebook

I am trying to find a regex that looks forward for the start of the next line that starts with a time stamp.

I am not sure if regex would get me past multiple lines.

This fails with the 'new line' in the look forward near the end.

```
regex = re.compile(
    '(?P<time>(\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}.\d{3}))'
    '(?P<a>\s(\[T\:))?'
    '(?P<token>\d{15})?'
    '(?P<b>(\]\s{))?'
    '(?P<event_type>.*\:\d)?'
    '(?P<c>\}\s)'
    '(?P<message>.*)'
    '(?=^\d{2}\d{2})'
```

This works but breaks the last message at the \d{2}\d{2} but it has to be in the same line, not the next line.

```
regex = re.compile(
    '(?P<time>(\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}.\d{3}))'
    '(?P<a>\s(\[T\:))?'
    '(?P<token>\d{15})?'
    '(?P<b>(\]\s{))?'
    '(?P<event_type>.*\:\d)?'
    '(?P<c>\}\s)'
    '(?P<message>.*)'
    '(?=\d{2}\d{2})'
```

I am testing the regex with this:

```
with open(ors_log) as f:
    for m in regex.finditer(f.read()):
        if m:
            print(m.group('time', 'a', 'token', 'b', 'event_type', 'c', 'message'))
```

I have tried stackoverflow suggestions:

```
with open(ors_log) as f:
    for m in regex.finditer(f.read(), re.MULTILINE):
```

and

```
(?=\n\d{2}\d{2})')
```

Any thoughts ideas are much appreciated, thank you.

```
15:36:32.448 [T:140113529200000] {ScxmlMetric:3} METRIC <log sid='~456~1TF8DKFD49SRE6Q9PE0C2LAES00000J' expr='~456~01TF8DKFD49SRE6Q9PE0C2LAES00000J: Inside Screen Block: Priorities' label='' level='2' />
15:36:32.448 [T:14011340184339] {ScxmlMetric:1} METRIC <extension sid='~456~01TF8DKFD49we4rf5g6h7C2LAES00000J' name='screen' namespace='https://lab.io/modules' />
15:36:32.448 ==>Connector::ConnHandler  Port=0 Proto=0 CallBack=<9740>
===>event:   event_id=3, id=0 handle=66, datasize=24 
15:36:32.448 {Thread:3} HandleThreadData: << 24 bytes <<
15:36:32.448 {Link:3} Message 'request' sent to 'IP'
    attr_ref_id [int] = 999530875
    attr_envelope [list, size (unpacked)=369] = 
       'Version' [str] = "1.0"
       'AppType' [int] = 90
       'Service' [str] = "Screen"
15:36:34.222 {ThreadSync:3} HandleThreadData: << 24 bytes <<
```

message 1

```
METRIC <log sid='~456~1TF8DKFD49SRE6Q9PE0C2LAES00000J' expr='~456~01TF8DKFD49SRE6Q9PE0C2LAES00000J: Inside Screen Block: Priorities' label='' level='2' />
```

message 2

```
METRIC <extension sid='~456~01TF8DKFD49we4rf5g6h7C2LAES00000J' name='screen' namespace='https://lab.io/modules' />
```

message 3

```
==>Connector::ConnHandler   Port=0 Proto=0 CallBack=<9740>
===>event:   event_id=3, id=0 handle=66, datasize=24
```

message 4

```
HandleThreadData: << 24 bytes <<
```

message 5

```
Message 'request' sent to 'IP'
    attr_ref_id [int] = 999530875
    attr_envelope [list, size (unpacked)=369] = 
       'Version' [str] = "1.0"
       'AppType' [int] = 90
       'Service' [str] = "Screen"
```

message 6

```
HandleThreadData: << 24 bytes <<
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the data of the 4 named capture groups, and multiple lines for the `message`:

```
(?P<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3})(?:\s\[T:(?P<token>\d{14,})])?(?:\s{(?P<event_type>[^:]+:\d+)})?(?P<message>.*(?:\n(?!\d{2}:\d{2}\:\d{2}\.\d{3}\b).*)*)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?P<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3})` Named group *time* (note to escape the dot `\.` and you don't have to escape `:`)
- `(?:\s\[T:(?P<token>\d{14,})])?` Optional group,  match  `[T:` and capture in named group *token* Match 14 or more digits (or `{15}` if always 15 and there is a typo in the example data)
- `(?:\s{(?P<event_type>[^:]+:\d+)})?` Optional group, match  `{` and then capture in group *event_type* 1+ chars other than `:` Then `:` and 1+ digits and match the closing `}`
- `(?P<message>` Named group *message*

  - `.*` Match the whole line
  - `(?:\n(?!\d{2}:\d{2}\:\d{2}\.\d{3}\b).*)*` Match all following lines that do not start with a time like pattern
- `)`  Close the group

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EV2w2n/1).

**Note** that there are 14 digits here instead of 15 `[T:14011340184339]`